# Can you run a maven job with the SoapUI plugin that uses HermesJMS on Jenkins?

Tags: maven, soap, jenkins

I have a project that I run Soap UI/HermesJMS tests against after building and deploying. I would like to automate this process by getting Jenkins to build, autodeploy and then run the Soap UI/HermesJMS tests, so that I can don't have to monitor and run the tests myself. Is there a way to set this sort of flow up?

Comment: There were a few results on google that give partial answers to this problem, but nothing that answers the overall process, so I decided to create a Q&A of how I solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to set this kind of system up.

First, in my implementation I run the Soap UI tests in a completely different build on Jenkins. When the job for the project you want to test completes successfully and has deployed to a testing environment you can instruct Jenkins to then run dependent jobs, like a Soap UI job.

The Soap UI project exists in its own code repository, which hooks into Jenkins through one of the many different SCM plugins. When either a job that should be tested runs successfully, or the tests are updated, it can trigger Jenkins to run the tests.

The code repository itself runs a maven pom that includes the following:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
    <artifactId>soapui-pro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle.drivers</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <id>Test Cases</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <projectFile>/path/to/project/file</projectFile>
                <settingsFile>/path/to/settings/file</settingsFile>
                <outputFolder>output</outputFolder>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <printReport>false</printReport>
                <soapuiProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>soapui.ext.libraries</name>
                        <value>/path/to/ext/libraries</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>soapui.logroot</name>
                        <value>/path/where/logs/go</value>
                    </property>
                </soapuiProperties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When you the plugin is run it will look for XMLs for its settings and the project of test cases that it will run. These are the only Soap UI files that you will need to include, besides any files that contain messages you want to send/compare against in your tests.

Now, although a Hermes plugin does exist for Maven, I'm unaware of any way to point Soap UIs settings file to look at the maven plugin. Instead I've had to opt to include a full Hermes installation as part of the project. Which is one of the reasons why I recommend having Soap UI exist as its own plugin that runs in its own Jenkins job.

Inside the Soap UI settings page you can find this line:

```
<con:setting id="ToolsSettings@hermesjms">/path/to/hermesJMS</con:setting>
```

Next inside the hermes-config file, which is normally stored under your home directory inside /.hermes, you will need to edit it to change where it looks for the hermes installation. The following is an excrept of the first few arguments which are the ones that you need to change:

```
<config lastEditedByUser="S" lastEditedByHermesVersion="v1.14 SoapUI" maxThreadPoolSize="5" auditDirectory="Hermes\temp" messageFilesDir="Hermes\.hermes\.\messages" ... />
```

If you experience problems with HermesJMS connecting to your test environment I would suggest checking near the bottom of the hermes configuration environment to see if the following settings are explicitly set to the values, as when I ran it locally, and then on the Jenkins server it couldn't seem to resolve some of the values that had been set:

```
<extension className="hermes.ext.weblogic.WebLogicJMSAdminFactory">
    <properties>
        <property name="jmsServer" value="yourJmsServer"/>
        <property name="webLogicDomain" value="mydomain"/>
        <property name="webLogicServer" value="yourWeblogicServer/ClusterYouDeployTo"/>
    </properties>
</extension>
```

This is not an ideal system, if it's possible to link to Mavens hermes plugin in the Soap UI settings then it would be neater to not have to include hermes in the project files. After extensive searching, if it is possible, then no one has documented it.